# Create subgraph query in Gremlin around single node with outgoing and incoming edges

Tags: cypher, gremlin, graph-databases, janusgraph

I have a large Janusgraph database and I'd to create a subgraph centered around one node type and including incoming and outgoing nodes of specific types.

In Cypher, the query would look like this:

```
MATCH (a:Journal)N-[:PublishedIn]-(b:Paper{paperTitle:'My Paper Title'})<-[:AuthorOf]-(c:Author) 
RETURN a,b,c
```

This is what I tried in Gremlin:

```
sg = g.V().outE('PublishedIn').subgraph('j_p_a').has('Paper','paperTitle', 'My Paper Title')
     .inE('AuthorOf').subgraph('j_p_a')
     .cap('j_p_a').next()
```

But I get a syntax error. 'AuthorOf' and 'PublishedIn' are not the only edge types ending at 'Paper' nodes.

Can someone show me how to correctly execute this query in Gremlin?

Comment: The `outE` step will yield edges, the `has` step will check properties on those edges, following that you should be using an `inV` not an `inE`. Without your data model it is hard to know exactly what you need but probably you need `inV().outE()` or something like that as you need to follow a pattern of Edge-Vertex-Edge. The `inV` may need to go before the has looking at the Cypher query.

Comment: I'll add an answer that I think reflects your Cypher query. Without the data model I cannot test this easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written in your query, the `outE` step yields edges and the `has` step will check properties on those edges, following that the query processor will expect an `inV` not another `inE`. Without your data model it is hard to know exactly what you need, however, looking at the Cypher I think this is what you want.

```
sg = g.V().outE('PublishedIn').
           subgraph('j_p_a').
           inV().
           has('Paper','paperTitle', 'My Paper Title').
           inE('AuthorOf').
           subgraph('j_p_a')
           cap('j_p_a').
           next()
```

**Edited to add:**

As I do not have your data I used my air-routes graph. I modeled this query on yours and used some `select` steps to limit the data size processed. This seems to work in my testing. Hopefully you can see the changes I made and try those in your query.

```
sg = g.V().outE('route').as('a').
      inV().
      has('code','AUS').as('b').
      select('a').
      subgraph('sg').
      select('b').
      inE('contains').
      subgraph('sg').
      cap('sg').
      next()
```

Comment: I've accepted the answer because it seems to have solved the syntax problem I was having and makes sense based on the explanation. But the query times-out when I try to run it. I have an index on the 'paperTitle' property to facilitate fuzzy searching. Do you have any insights about bottlenecks in this query?

Comment: If you try using a few limit(10) steps do you see some results. How many edges/vertices do you expect this query to be touching?

Comment: If I use the exact 'paperTitle' there should be one 'Paper' node, one 'Journal' node and 4-6 Author nodes.

Comment: Ok So as the query as written starts by looking at every vertex in the Graph it is going to look potentially at a lot of edges. I'll try to edit my answer to restrict that part.